# Change Edittext focus and make an ImageView disappear

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working on an app which has two EditTexts and two ImageViews (my ImageView is a delete icon EditText)

I want that when I set the focus on EditText1, ImageView1 appears and ImageView2 disappears and when I set the focus on EditText2, ImageView2 appears and ImageView1 disappears.

I think I should use the `TextWatcher()` methods instead of `setOnKeyListener()`, but I don't know how to.

I wrote this code in the `onCreate()` method, but I have one problem: when I set the focus on EditText1, I have to write something in it to make image_1 appear  and image_2 disappear (and vice-versa  when I set the focus on EditText2)

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            image_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return false;
        }
    });
    editText2.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            image_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            image_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try using setOnFocusChangeListener for the edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `OnKeyListener` or `TextWatcher` would be the correct solution to your demand.

What you want here instead is `OnFocusChangeListener`:

```
    View.OnFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener1 = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            image_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
        }
    }
    editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener1);

    View.OnFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener2 = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            image_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            image_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener2);
```

Comment: yeap...that's it
I've written this code in onCreate() method and that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use TextChangedListener:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });


editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

I hope it can help you.